# javascript sequential execution - deferred object etc

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to count the number of images loaded into a page after certain time interval ( lets say 6 seconds) then need to do some processing.So after 6 seconds I am invoking scan_images_results ( ) function.

```
function scan_images_results ( ) {
   $.when(count_loaded_image()).then(function() {
    window.console.log("i m here");
    });
}

function count_loaded_image() {
    var counter = 0;
    $('img[id^="picThumbImg_"]').imagesLoaded()
        .progress( function( instance, image ) {
            var result = image.isLoaded ? 'loaded' : 'broken';
            console.log( 'image is ' + result + ' for ' + image.img.src );
        if(image.isLoaded) {
            counter++;
        }

        });

    console.log('counter--'+counter);
}
```

Output is as below.

```
counter--0
i m here
image is broken for https://myserver/cgi-bin/sf?f=58343d875e7a10290d0464cabfc276e5.jpg
image is broken for https://myserver/cgi-bin/sf?f=68343d875e7a10290d0464cabfc276e6.jpg
image is broken for https://myserver/cgi-bin/sf?f=78343d875e7a10290d0464cabfc276e7.jpg
.........
........ 28 times
```

I am using "https://github.com/desandro/imagesloaded" to check if image is loaded or not.I am getting 28 images broken, which is correct count.But my counter function is being getting executed later.i.e. my expected output is

```
image is broken for https://myserver/cgi-bin/sf?f=58343d875e7a10290d0464cabfc276e5.jpg
image is broken for https://myserver/cgi-bin/sf?f=68343d875e7a10290d0464cabfc276e6.jpg
image is broken for https://myserver/cgi-bin/sf?f=78343d875e7a10290d0464cabfc276e7.jpg
.........
........ 28 times 
counter--0
I m here
```

I know where is the problem? I need to execute the function in sequence and for that I need to create Deferred Objects. But I could not ab able to fix my problem.

Comment: `scan_images_results ` doesn't return a promise object, therefore passing it into $.when is pointless.

Comment: You likely just need to `return $('img[id^="picThumbImg_"]').imagesLoaded()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need `$.when`, you don't even need the additional function.

```
function scan_images_results() {
    var counter = 0;
    $('img[id^="picThumbImg_"]').imagesLoaded()
        .progress(function (instance, image) {
            var result = image.isLoaded ? 'loaded' : 'broken';
            console.log('image is ' + result + ' for ' + image.img.src);
            if (image.isLoaded) {
                counter++;
            }

        })
        .always(function () {
            console.log("I'm here");
        });

    console.log('counter--' + counter);
}
```

and if you wanted to keep the function,

```
function scan_images_results() {
    count_loaded_image().always(function () {
        console.log("I'm here");
    });
}

function count_loaded_image() {
    var counter = 0;
    return $('img[id^="picThumbImg_"]').imagesLoaded().progress(function (instance, image) {
        var result = image.isLoaded ? 'loaded' : 'broken';
        console.log('image is ' + result + ' for ' + image.img.src);
        if (image.isLoaded) {
            counter++;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for help.. So you are using imagesloaded
 always event here. I have just placed 'console.log('counter--' + counter);' inside always event only like below.It is as expected.  .always(function () {
            console.log("I'm here");
            console.log('counter--' + counter);
        });

Comment: Yes, i used always because based on the ouptut you are seeing, done will never be called, only fail and always since some of the images aren't loading properly.

Comment: I just want one more confirmation -- Should I need to trigger scan_images_results() after 6 seconds or I can trigger it immediately as I mentioned ?I think I can call it immediately.

Comment: What is the 6 seconds for? you should be able to trigger it immediately.

Comment: Actually images are being served from proxy server. So if proxy server is highly loaded then it could not server image immediately. there will be some delay. So if anytime image is not loaded in 6 second I want to change the URL with other.I think here that imagesloaded will handle this situation. am I right?

Comment: You could possibly do something with that within the progress handler. when an image is broken, change it's url, then if you get the fail callback in the end, re-run the imagesLoaded method.

Comment: Don't forget to make sure when you re-run it you only run it on the failed images, otherwise you're just contributing to the over-usage of the proxy server.

Comment: How it is possible? I think imagesLoaded will not make any extra request to proxy server as I am checking in firebug.So it should not overload the proxy server. Please correct me if I am wrong as I am writing this code for highly loaded environment.